# Rails: rewrite a find_all_by() with a .where method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using a gem that doesnt work on the arrays from the find_all_by() method, but does with the .where(); however, I don't know how to write it in a way that produces the same result.

For instance, how could I rewrite:

```
Post.find_all_by_poster(@user.id , :conditions => ['title IS NOT NULL OR name !=?', 'Bob' ])
```

My attempt:

```
Post.where("poster = ? AND title !=? OR name !=?", @user.id, 'NULL', 'Bob')
```

Any ideas? I'm having trouble satisfying the same conditions. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Look into [MetaWhere](http://metautonomo.us/projects/metawhere/) to get away from having to write SQL fragments in your code.

Comment: appreciate the suggestion, seems like it could really help boost my productivity! i will start practicing with it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You still need to use `IS NOT NULL` instead of passing in `NULL` as a separate parameter:

```
Post.where("poster = ? and (title is not null or name != ?)", @user.id, 'Bob')
```